# Create new row for every 3 items Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

Basically the code works fine but I am not able to change the order of the elements. 
 At the moment the result looks like this:

[image]

But actually I would like it like this:

[image]

My code Looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <el-container>
      <el-row v-for="story of chunkedItems" :key="story.id">
        <el-col v-for="item of story" :key="item.id">
          <el-card>
            <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
            <div>{{ item.text }}</div>
          </el-card>
        </el-col>
      </el-row>
    </el-container>
  </div>
</template>

computed: {
    chunkedItems() {
      return this.$_.chunk(this.stories, 3);
    },
  },
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it can be done by CSS ````el-container { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the chunk and use `:span="8"` instead.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <el-container>
      <el-row>
        <el-col :span="8" v-for="item of stories" :key="item.id">
          <el-card>
            <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
            <div>{{ item.text }}</div>
          </el-card>
        </el-col>
      </el-row>
    </el-container>
  </div>
</template>

computed: {
},
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! Obviously I did not understand the `span` attribute too well.

Comment: np, [is in the docs](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/layout#column-spacing) 3/24 = 8, if you want weird cols like your example use modulo `:span="index % 2 == 0 ? 12:3" v-for="(item, index) in stories"`